# Get auto increment keys has different behavior between JDBC and MySQL client during insert multi with key in one sql

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Create test table:

```sql
create table t1(
  id integer auto_increment primary key,
  name varchar(32)
);
```

MySQL can insert multi values separated by comma in one SQL and try to get auto_increment key as below:

```sql
-- use MySQL client:
insert into t1(id, name) values (1, 'apple'),(2,'banana');
select LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

The `select LAST_INSERT_ID()` result will be 0, because [MySQL Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) said:

> The value of `LAST_INSERT_ID()` is not changed if you set the AUTO_INCREMENT column of a row to a non-“magic” value (that is, a value that is not NULL and not 0).

Now, let's try java program with JDBC:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String sql = "insert into t1(id, name) values(3, 'orange'),(4, 'pear')";
    try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS)) {
        PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        stmt.executeUpdate();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.print("ID: " + rs.getInt(1));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

We will get the incorrect result (0,0 or 3,4 should as expected):

```
ID: 4
ID: 5
```

Diving into the JDBC code, we can find the `updateId`=4 is return by MySQL:

```java
# com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.result.OkPacket#parse

ok.setUpdateID(buf.readInteger(IntegerDataType.INT_LENENC)); // last_insert_id
```

But MySQL should not return `updateId`=4. As [MySQL reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) said, the `updateId` should be 3.

> `function_last-insert-id` : If you insert multiple rows using a single INSERT statement, LAST_INSERT_ID() returns the value generated for the first inserted row only.

And JDBC driver thinks the result should be 3.

```java
// JDBC driver calc multi ids by add increment on `insertId`
// com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl#getGeneratedKeysInternal(long)
if ((beginAt != 0 /* BIGINT UNSIGNED can wrap the protocol representation */) && (numKeys > 0)) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numKeys; i++) {
        byte[][] row = new byte[1][];
        if (beginAt > 0) {
            row[0] = StringUtils.getBytes(Long.toString(beginAt));
        } else {
            // ignored...
        }
        rowSet.add(new ByteArrayRow(row, getExceptionInterceptor()));
        // add increment as next id
        beginAt += this.connection.getAutoIncrementIncrement();
    }
}
```

Enable MySQL Query Log, but can not get useful info:

```
2022-07-26T02:38:14.303740Z    62 Connect   xxx@1.1.1.1 on test using SSL/TLS
2022-07-26T02:38:14.338218Z    62 Query /* mysql-connector-java-8.0.29 (Revision: dd61577595edad45c398af508cf91ad26fc4144f) */SELECT  @@session.auto_increment_increment AS auto_increment_increment, @@character_set_client AS character_set_client, @@character_set_connection AS character_set_connection, @@character_set_results AS character_set_results, @@character_set_server AS character_set_server, @@collation_server AS collation_server, @@collation_connection AS collation_connection, @@init_connect AS init_connect, @@interactive_timeout AS interactive_timeout, @@license AS license, @@lower_case_table_names AS lower_case_table_names, @@max_allowed_packet AS max_allowed_packet, @@net_write_timeout AS net_write_timeout, @@performance_schema AS performance_schema, @@query_cache_size AS query_cache_size, @@query_cache_type AS query_cache_type, @@sql_mode AS sql_mode, @@system_time_zone AS system_time_zone, @@time_zone AS time_zone, @@transaction_isolation AS transaction_isolation, @@wait_timeout AS wait_timeout
2022-07-26T02:38:14.386780Z    62 Query SHOW WARNINGS
2022-07-26T02:38:14.418325Z    62 Query SET character_set_results = NULL
2022-07-26T02:38:14.454823Z    62 Query SET autocommit=1
2022-07-26T02:38:14.502757Z    62 Query insert into t1(id, name) values(15, 'orange'),(16, 'pear')
2022-07-26T02:38:14.549495Z    62 Quit
```

Questions:

1. Compare the difference between MySQL client and JDBC result, can we guess MySQL does not use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` during JDBC access generated keys?
2. But what is the mechanism during JDBC access generated keys? (`updateId`=4 but not 3)

Of course, if we do not set `id` in SQL and then get generated keys, everything will be correct.

MySQL version: 5.7.32-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
JDBC driver version:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.29</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Enable General Log and look what queries are received by MySQL.

Comment: @Akina I have added MySQL query log to the questioin, but I think there is no useful info in the log.

Comment: *Enable MySQL Query Log, but can not get useful info* Log tells that AI value was not generated. *can we guess MySQL do not use LAST_INSERT_ID()* No.

Comment: *the select LAST_INSERT_ID() result will be 0* Depends on previous queries in this connection. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=58b50f75aee49cdc3c4f7019ff000044